# Shortcut keys do not work in a Custom Panel in a Visio 2013 add-in

Tags: c#, .net, visio

I have created add-in for Visio but I have some problem related to Custom Panel.  For implementing Custom Panel in Visio I used solution described in next link:

[How can you add a Custom Panel in a Visio 2013 add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518156/how-can-you-add-a-custom-panel-in-a-visio-2013-add-in)

My Custom Panel contain TextBoxes and Buttons. Buttons work correct and I can type text into any TextBox but I CAN'T insert text by using shortcut(Ctrl+V). When I type Ctrl+V my text is inserted in new shape of opened document. Another commands like Ctrl+X Ctrl+A etc do not work too.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio intercepts many keyboard events before they reach your add-in. It provides "KeystrokeMessageForAddon" event though. You could check how it can be used in one of my Visio projects (it is specialized a bit for browser control but I hope it will give you an idea)
https://github.com/nbelyh/HtmlFormData/blob/master/HtmlFormData/HtmlFormData/ShortcutManager.cs

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your add-in works well. I have tried to use "OnKeystrokeMessageForAddon" event in my application but it is never received. Also I tried to allow the "OnKeystrokeMessageForAddon" event in Event monitor of Visio but it did not help me.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @OleksiyKovalchyk Well, have you subscribed to this event? https://github.com/nbelyh/HtmlFormData/blob/master/HtmlFormData/HtmlFormData/ThisAddIn.cs#L151 For the even monitor, you need to add it in options (tools -> options -> events)

Comment: Yes, of course. I have done this all but event does not occur.

Comment: Hard to tell then, especially without seeing the code.. usually it does occur. Maybe events are disabled in Visio settings?

Comment: Thank you for help I have resolved problem with event.
My project created by Add-in Express that is why i used Interop.Visio.dll provided by it. But when library was changed to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.dll, then "OnKeystrokeMessageForAddon" event started to receive.